# Monster perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, bash

I'm trying to change strings like this:

```
<a href='../Example/case23.html'><img src='Blablabla.jpg'
```

To this:

```
<a href='../Example/case23.html'><img src='<?php imgname('case23'); ?>'
```

And I've got this monster of a regular expression:

```
find . -type f | xargs perl -pi -e \
  's/<a href=\'(.\.\.\/Example\/)(case\d\d)(.\.html\'><img src=\')*\'/\1\2\3<\?php imgname\(\'\2\'); \?>\'/'
```

But it isn't working. In fact, I think it's a problem with Bash, which could probably be pointed out rather quickly.

```
r: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
r: line 4: `  's/<a href=\'(.\.\.\/Example\/)(case\d\d)(.\.html\'><img src=\')*\'/\1\2\3<\?php imgname\(\'\2\'); \?>\'/''
```

But if you want to help me with the regular expression that'd be cool, too!

Comment: don't parse HTML with regular expressions. use something like HTML::Parser, HTML::TreeBuilder, or HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath

Comment: [Friends don't let friends parse HTML with regular expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: also check-out bash heredocs http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html . Handy for long bash commands that contain quotes and other shell meta-characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teaching you how to fish:

```
s/…/…/
```

Use a separator other than `/` for the `s` operator because `/` already occurs in the expression.

```
s{…}{…}
```

Cut down on backslash quoting, prefer `[.]` over `\.` because we'll shellquote later. Let's keep backslashes only for the necessary or important parts, namely here the digits character class.

```
s{<a href='[.][.]/Example/case(\d\d)[.]html'>…
```

Capture only the variable part. No need to reassemble the string later if the most part is static.

```
s{<a href='[.][.]/Example/case(\d\d)[.]html'><img src='[^']*'}{<a href='../Example/case$1.html'><img src='<?php imgname('case$1'); ?>'}
```

Use `$1` instead of `\1` to denote backreferences. `[^']*` means everything until the next `'`.

To serve now as the argument for the Perl `-e` option, this program needs to be shellquoted. Employ the following helper program, you can also use an alias or shell function instead:

```
> cat `which shellquote`
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use String::ShellQuote qw(shell_quote); undef $/; print shell_quote <>
```

Run it and paste the program body, terminate input with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, you receive:

```
's{<a href='\''[.][.]/Example/case(\d\d)[.]html'\''><img src='\''[^'\'']*'\''}{<a href='\''../Example/case$1.html'\''><img src='\''<?php imgname('\''case$1'\''); ?>'\''}'
```

Put this together with shell pipeline.

```
find . -type f | xargs perl -pi -e 's{<a href='\''[.][.]/Example/case(\d\d)[.]html'\''><img src='\''[^'\'']*'\''}{<a href='\''../Example/case$1.html'\''><img src='\''<?php imgname('\''case$1'\''); ?>'\''}'
```

Comment: That's not single quotes permitting escapes. That's "open-quote, close-quote, escape-quote (unquoted/outside of quotes), open-quote, ..."

Comment: +1 for taking the time to explain in so much detail how to solve this problem step-by-step. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Bash single-quotes do not permit any escapes.

Try this at a bash prompt and you'll see what I mean:

FOO='\'foo'

will cause it to prompt you looking for the fourth single-quote. If you satisfy it, you'll find FOO's value is

\foo

You'll need to use double-quotes around your expression. Although in truth, your HTML should be using double-quotes in the first place.

Comment: Also, as others have said, regular expressions are not the best way to parse HTML. But if your case really is limited to a pattern as relatively simple as this, you can probably get away with it.

Comment: Downvote: This is wrong, single quotes *do* permit escapes (see my answer for proof), and therefore double quotes are *not* needed. Double quotes are very inconvenient anyway, many Perl variables such as `$_` or `$1` are going to be interpreted as shell variables. To keep one's sanity, always `-e''`, never `-e""`.

Comment: @daxim: That's wrong, they don't. See my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes within single quotes in Bash:

```
set -xv
echo ''"'"''
echo $'\''
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a one-liner.  Put your Perl code in a script, which makes it much easier to get the regex right without wondering about escaping quotes and such.

I'd use a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -pi

use strict;
use warnings;

s{
    ( <a \b [^>]* \b href=['"] [^'"]*/case(\d+)\.html ['"] [^>]* > \s*
      <img \b [^>]* \b src=['"] ) [^'"<] [^'"]*
}{$1<?php imgname('case$2'); ?>}gix;
```

and then do something like:

```
find . -type f | xargs fiximgs
```

– Michael

Answer (score 0):

if you install the package mysql, it comes with a command called replace.

With the replace command you can:

```
while read line 
do
 X=`echo $line| replace "<a href='../Example/"  ""|replace ".html'><" " "|awk '{print $1}'`
 echo "<a href='../Example/$X.html'><img src='<?php imgname('$X'); ?>'">NewFile   
done < myfile
```

same can be done with sed.  sed s/'my string'/'replace string'/g..   replace is just easier to work with special characters.